# Mysql multiple table join special case

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join, union, outer-join

here is my scenario: I have 3 tables:

```
items table

item_id |name
----------------
1       |item 1
2       |item 2
etc

stocks table

stock_id |item_id |quantity 
---------------------------
1        |1       |10
2        |2       |20
etc

sales_item tables
sales_item_id |sales_id |item_id |price
---------------------------------------
1             |1        |1       |100
2             |1        |2       |200
etc
```

Here is the joined result I want to achieve:

```
joined table

item_id |name  |stock_id |quantity |sales_item_id |sales_id |price
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1       |item1 |1        |10       |null          |null     |null
1       |item1 |null     |null     |1             |1        |100
2       |item2 |2        |10       |null          |null     |null
2       |item2 |null     |null     |2             |1        |200
```

I hope I made it clear. Is there any way to achieve this result? I have tried left, right, outer join and union and I have already tried to search on the internet, just it cannot represent by keyword, but still cannot find the answer. I hope you guy understand. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a `UNION` of two `INNER JOIN`s. One gets the information from `stock` and has `NULL` values in the columns from `sales_item`, the other gets information from `sales_item` and has `NULL` for the columns from `stock`.

```
SELECT i.item_id, i.name, s.stock_id, s.quantity, NULL AS sales_item_id, NULL AS sales_id, NULL AS price
FROM items AS i
JOIN stocks AS s ON s.item_id = i.item_id
UNION
SELECT i.item_id, i.name, NULL, NULL, si.sales_item_id, si.sales_id, si.price
FROM items AS i
JOIN sales_item AS si ON i.item_id = si.item_id
```

Comment: last line, is it, i.item_id instead of s.item_id ?

Answer (score 0):

All the nulls in your example shows that you are trying to join together two completely different result sets: join the items with the stock and get all that data, then join the items with the sales and return all that data.  The trickiness is that you have two different kinds of results in your desired join table.  The only thing both sets have in common is an item id and name.

A union (which is what you are going to have to use) requires both sets to have the same number of columns.  However, your sets have a different number of columns, and very little overlap.  As a result you have to explicitly "select" some non-existent columns as placeholders.  So your final query should look something like this:

Working through the parts you have two join statements:

```
SELECT items.item_id, items.name, stocks.stock_id, stocks.quantity FROM items JOIN stocks ON stocks.item_id=items.id
```

That gets your items + stock information.  Then another join to get sales data:

```
SELECT items.item_id, items.name, sales.sales_item_id, sales.sales_id, sales.price FROM items JOIN sales_item ON sales_item.item_id=items.item_id
```

These are your two queries that need to be joined.  Of course, you could right these a bit shorter by leaving out some table references in the select and using a different join syntax, but you get the idea.  The exact type of join you want to do here will depend on your underlying problem, so I'm just guessing at a plain JOIN (which is an alias for INNER JOIN).

Now you need to put them together with a UNION, and when you do that you have to add in some more columns as placeholders:

```
SELECT items.item_id, items.name, stocks.stock_id, stocks.quantity, null AS sales_item_id, null AS sales_id, null AS price FROM items JOIN stocks ON stocks.item_id=items.id
UNION ALL
SELECT items.item_id, items.name, null AS stock_id, null AS quantity, sales.sales_item_id, sales.sales_id, sales.price FROM items JOIN sales_item ON sales_item.item_id=items.item_id
```

And then (if needed) you can throw in a sort:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT items.item_id, items.name, stocks.stock_id, stocks.quantity, null AS sales_item_id, null AS sales_id, null AS price FROM items JOIN stocks ON stocks.item_id=items.id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT items.item_id, items.name, null AS stock_id, null AS quantity, sales.sales_item_id, sales.sales_id, sales.price FROM items JOIN sales_item ON sales_item.item_id=items.item_id
) U order by item_id ASC
```

Comment: in your query, its not items.id, it is items.item_id and instead of sales.sales_item_id, sales.sales_id instead of sales, its sales_item needed